# GridView Row Does not get select or Affected When Checkbox checked on Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using **WPF Application Form with Telerik Gridview** using C#.

In that Gridview i inserted checkboxes using **Data template**.

Its created but **when i click or check the checkbox the current row is not getting selected.**

*How can i solve this problem?*

Please anyone tell me the solution of this problem.

My xaml code for creating checkbox in grid is:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

In that checkbox i have created click event.

And also i want **to know the current row number of the CheckBox Placed row in the gridview in checkbox click event**. Give me some suggestion for this.

Here My CheckBox Click event Code:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox selectedCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    //this.selectedCasePackRadGrid -- This is my gridview
    // Here I want to get the selected row number
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nowhere do I see you actually select the current row.

Comment: I am not able to get current row of the gridview in CheckBox click event. Can you plese let me know how can i acheive this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this custom control works, but I'm assuming you can access it via the `Parent` property, at some level.

Comment: please! Can you send the sample code for it? Then only i can able to do that

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how it would work; it's just a concept.

Comment: You just tell me a sample for it. I'll try and let you know .

Comment: You should be able to get the row using the DataContext property.  If you number the rows then you can get to a number that equals the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see you actually setting the row as `Selected` anywhere.

Your binding currently is setting a property in your DataContext called `IsSelected`. If this property actually exists, you can bind it to `GridViewRow.IsSelected` in a style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
</Style>
```

If it doesn't exist in your data object, you need to use a `RelativeSource` binding to find the `GridViewRow` and bind to it's `IsSelected` property

```
Checked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}}, Path=IsSelected}"
```

As for finding the row number, there is no `RowIndex` property I know of that you can use to find the row number.  One alternative is to get the GridView's `ItemsSource` and call `IndexOf(dataobject)`, however that does break the separation of MVVM layers

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var dataItem = checkBox.DataContext as MyDataItem;
    var parentDataObject = myGridView.ItemsSource as SomeDataObject;

    if (dataItem == null || parentDataObject == null)
        return;

    var index = parentDataObject.SomeCollection.IndexOf(dataItem);
    // Do something with index
}
```

There are also other alternatives such as setting `AlternationCount` to something higher than the the number of rows, and accessing `GridViewRow.AlternationIndex`, although I don't know if that will work with Telerik's `GridView`

But perhaps the best thing you could do is evaluate what you actually need the index for, and see if you can use some other alternative to accomplish what you want. For example, if you want to pass the index of the selected row to a button command, it would be better to just pass the `SelectedItem` as the CommandParameter.

Comment: Rachel, Its Great.Now My gridview row is getting selected when checkbox checked by using your code.Thank you so much for your wonderful code. Its very useful for me to do my work. Thank you Yar. :-) You are too great :-)